# Jenkins trigger a job only after one has completed and avoid parallel execution of jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two jobs in Jenkins: Job A that gets triggered on a commit and job B. Technically job B is triggered only after job A has been completed as job B is mentioned as a downstream of job A in the post build actions, but imagine this scenario:

Job A has been triggered by one commit and is running while the job B is still running from previous commit of job A, this is causing potential failures and complexity as both are running in parallel.

What is the best way to *prevent* both of them running in parallel?

These are the plugins I saw on jenkins wiki:

[Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin)
[Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

Still wanted to know the best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Multijob plugin for this and then both sub jobs will be wrapped in one job that is triggered by a commit.

You can avoid parallel execution of that job (in case of 2 commits in short time, the 1st commit will trigger the job, the 2nd will be 'pending')

Comment: Also consider to configure them to run sequentially in order to *really* prevent them of being executed in parallel. This may be the case if there are multiple build processors.